# Extjs 6 State management issue with touch devies

Tags: state, extjs6

I am working in extjs6. I have grid with several columns as well as settings button on grid which hides/shows selected columns on click of apply button. I have implemented state related functionality for each column which will helps to decide which columns to be shown initially when user logs in.
    Suppose i have grid with columns as-
{Id,
Name,
Description,
Author,
CreatedOn,
ModifiedOn}
    I have selected Id, name and description columns. So as per my functionality, when i log out and again logs into my application, Code checks state of columns and displays only these three columns. Everything is working fine if i use application on Desktop/PC
    But when i am performing above functionality with mobile or tab like touch devices, something weird happens. Using mobile if user A selects only some of columns of grid and get logout and log in again..He is able to see only selected columns as per requirement.
    but now if i get login with same user A but on desktop/PC, grid is retrieving some wrong state resulting into display of all available columns. [Grid should display only those columns which user had selected before last logout].
    So can someone please help me to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is saving state on the client side - meaning, if you login on a mobile phone, the state will be saved only on the phone in the browser.

If you log in on the Desktop, the state will be saved only in the browser with which you visited the site.

The state can be saved to Cookies, or better, [LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider.html)

If you want to save states across devices, you need a server-side solution, you can check for one [here](https://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/ext-js-4-preserving-state-on-the-server-2/)

Comment: thanx for reply. But i am still confused by your this line-"the state will be saved only in the browser with which you visited the site".  Because, suppose initially i am on chrome browser and selects few of columns and logs out. Then if i am doing login operation using firefox, then only those selected columns are appearing, not all columns.

Comment: Which state provider are you using? Is it cookies, LocalStorage, or your own?

Comment: I am using LocalStorage for state saving.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies & other site data from both browsers? And then try to login again? LocalStorage is local, meaning it will store data only in that browser - see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795461/html5-local-storage-across-different-browsers)

Comment: Actually,I am using LocalStorage for state saving. But after specific interval,we are sanding this localstorage saved data to server side to store it in database. So everytime while login,we are giving call to server to get state. Everything is working correctly in case of desktop. But after login from touch devices, its failing for desktop

Comment: I forgot about the most obvious thing - the modern toolkit doesn't have it's own state mechanism. If you have a custom implementation, some code would be very helpful in discovering the issue.